# How can I provide a ContextMenu in a ListView when using the support library?

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I'm having type issues when attempting to inflate a `ContextMenu` while making use of the `ActionBarSherlock` library, which as you know ultimately mimics/implements the Android support library.

There is a `SherlockFragmentActivity` which sets the layout content and within that content exists two fragments. One of those fragments is a `SherlockListFragment`. Within the `onCreate` of the `SherlockListFragment` I make a call to register for the `ContextMenu`.

`registerForContextMenu(getListView());`

The problem stems when attempting to inflate the menu.

```
listView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.lot_menu, contextMenu);
            }
        });
```

I am unable to call `inflate` due to the type specified within the method parameters, which it expects as `com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu` however the passed in type is `android.view.ContextMenu`.

I seem to be missing something as inflating a `Menu` within the action bar was trivial however the `ContextMenu` seems to be posing issues when making use of the support framework.

How do I register appropriately to make use of the support framework as needed and subsequently inflate the `ContextMenu`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `getMenuInflater()` instead of `getSupportMenuInflater()` for inflating into a `ContextMenu`.

Comment: Didn't even think to try that... So the support framework is not even needed in this instance since according to Android docs, `ContextMenu` has been around since API level 1. Makes sense.

Comment: @AaronMcIver: Bingo. Jake only created workalikes for the things that were needed for action bar-related stuff (directly or indirectly). So, if you wanted to use an action mode instead of a context menu, then you would need to work with ActionBarSherlock-specific stuff.